# parseFloat with decimals and toFixed

Tags: javascript

I am using selection dropdowns to calculate the sum of the prices. I need .00 and .50 instead of .5

```
<script>
  var executeSum = function() {

  var sum, a, b, c = 0

  var m4r1InfoMrP = document.getElementById("m4r1InfoMrP");
    if (m4r1InfoMrP) {
        a = parseFloat(m4r1InfoMrP.value);
    }

  var m4r1InfoMrS = document.getElementById("m4r1InfoMrS");
  if (m4r1InfoMrS) {
      b = parseFloat(m4r1InfoMrS.value);
  }

  var m4r1InfoMrD = document.getElementById("m4r1InfoMrD");
  if (m4r1InfoMrD) {
      c = parseFloat(m4r1InfoMrD.value);
  }

  sum = a + b + c;

 document.getElementById("m4r1InfoMrPS").value = formatNumber(sum);         // 1.00;

};

function formatNumber(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
}

executeSum();
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSB1d.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS77C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by just replacing `num.toString()` with `num.toFixed(2)` in `formatNumber` function like:

```js
function formatNumber(num) {
  return num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
}

console.log( formatNumber(12345) )
console.log( formatNumber(12345.5) )
```